# How to write stored procedures for JSON Web API data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json, stored-procedures

I haven't written a stored procedure as yet. I have just deserialised some JSON data from a Web API feed. I've got some console writelines to confirm the data is being deserialised, but need to replace them with writing stored procedures for each piece of data which can then be called from the DB in a view later on.

I've looked up writing stored procedures in VS but none look like they would work in this way. I'm assuming that within the foreach I need to execute a `SqlParameter` of some kind to write the data attribute from the JSON to the DB table and respective column. Just a little stuck on where to start.

My program to fetch data from the API looks like this.

```
private static async void UpdateStreetWebApiProperties()
{
       var client = new HttpClient();
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage
       {
           Method = HttpMethod.Get,
           RequestUri = new Uri("https://inventorymanchester.co.uk/api/property-feed/sales/search"),
           Headers =
{
    { "ContentType", "application/json" },
    { "Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNzU5YTJlZjZmYjY0MWE3NjRiZGE5ZjdmYzk2ZDNkMjAwN2IwNTk1MTMyZWJlYjhjMmQ0MTUyZDZlODcwZGI4ODRiOTFmMWEzMGE5NDA0ZWEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3MzQzNjAuNDA5OTY1LCJuYmYiOjE2NTU3MzQzNjAuNDA5OTcxLCJleHAiOjE5NzEzNTM1NjAuMTE2MzYzLCJzdWIiOiIxMzM0MjIiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsicHVibGljLWFwaSJdfQ.kxo8GVwKFRUgfyhrRqUrh6bQvJvv5PfJgken90RulA_hTKuX4zWPs6fZ6RkljSK1ECsPYfeNKF5Z_E-xYekRWtDKOcWCXp-wKKNfHWA7rwVU1NzzeghszqcQ0ojLqcqiJ_sxFXCyouvP6LW1-jlcWmYUaHrBu2rajSSyo-K3RN_uFq85Fc5_XkCAvTzO4U59ZcNU4nhRvj3SG2b4l0kZPGlTePkJafciToZ-Q618DYDtO1Q63hUY6X6CunjIIKXiw8h1o9qG9vlmV60JBuVZ4COzc05H-e4UrA3tYkxa6O6xi3baczCZFr97bTIwXMRlifUh8E6WS29T_2uIjSl5OIcaXLuDhrxYOUrfTsFuGU2SuwKKflps0jAUir1s_T_Fi4sPiC5BqvvbrPSBHXlNQpguIN6nYCK4FXW2ixALjs5e2JKN5gMmOCFeqzEmZJAkrHR0iN7n-UbWwsX7dh8ODss3XprckzadC-f_EHiY4ZDSdKPPnJTukkA0V-ezafoO-hBPeiiPOo-IH3kqCyElUMv2sosV4yaFT8DhFlrivCAktwXz4vkKTUYhjuueWU-QxX1y2MwE0zT32SKb21Bwp4Z7nJ0Fa84_CglbWWZZVglJh6Rrgmmg17DgxpSJx3qCiqqum3UrKGTYuLTube47zjumFQeyy1cYUWmqcRG84OQ" },
},
       };

       using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
       {
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               var properties = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  
               string strBufJSON = properties;
               // above is web service results

               JsonModel.JSONModel.Rootobject jData;

               jData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel.JSONModel.Rootobject>(strBufJSON);

               foreach (var data in jData.data)
               {
                   // now display some values
                   Console.WriteLine(data.attributes.public_url);
                   Console.WriteLine(data.attributes.inline_address);
                   Console.WriteLine(data.attributes.sale_status);
                   Console.WriteLine(data.attributes.bathrooms);
               }          
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Could not get properties");
           }
       }
}
```

I have outlined my table like this and matched my JSON data attributes to match the table columns in a hope it makes it easier. I'm running SQL Server 2014.

```
USE [TortoiseDB]
  GO

 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tortoise_Street_Properties]    
Script Date: 07/26/2022 11:54:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tortoise_Street_Properties](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Pid] [varchar](255) NULL,
[inlineaddress] [varchar](255) NULL,
[postcode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[description] [varchar](255) NULL,
[bedrooms] [varchar](255) NULL,
[price] [varchar](255) NULL,
[salestatus] [varchar](255) NULL,
[brochure] [varchar](255) NULL,
[longitude] [int] NULL,
[latitude] [int] NULL,
[virtualtour] [varchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

The JSON looks like the following also to add context:

```
{"data":[{"type":"property","id":"a91ab45e-5db8-4486-9bdf-f38dcb63c400","attributes":{"branch_uuid":"3e7a4a68-ab41-46c3-9a48-e3d1635cd056","inline_address":"101 London Road, Peterborough","public_address":"London Road, Peterborough, PE2","postcode":"PE2 9DD","bedrooms":5,"bathrooms":2,"receptions":2,"floor_area":null,"plot_area":null,"land_area":null,"property_type":"Detached House","property_age_bracket":null,"construction_year":null,"status":"For Sale","sale_status":"For Sale","lettings_status":null,"owner_label":"Vendor","tenure":null,"tenure_notes":null,"lease_expiry_year":null,"lease_expiry_date":null,"public_url":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/platform\/properties\/a91ab45e-5db8-4486-9bdf-f38dcb63c400","created_at":"2022-06-17T15:18:53+01:00","updated_at":"2022-07-12T11:23:11+01:00","custom_meta_data":[],"property_urls":[],"viewing_booking_url":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/platform\/properties\/a91ab45e-5db8-4486-9bdf-f38dcb63c400\/book-viewing"},"relationships":{"address":{"data":{"type":"address","id":"433518e4-d544-42ce-aba4-7d1137465af1"}},"details":{"data":{"type":"details","id":"1bf2b0fc-36c1-40f1-9e04-5b5cf72ffd0c"}},"salesListing":{"data":{"type":"sales_listing","id":"992114a6-3fcf-48b1-af1d-f5f3976a23da"}},"lettingsListing":{"data":null},"primaryImage":{"data":{"type":"media","id":"9ed40865-0873-4159-808b-5941faa520c9"}}}},{"type":"property","id":"4fd57964-71ea-4a77-b773-b4079a0f95dc","attributes":{"branch_uuid":"3e7a4a68-ab41-46c3-9a48-e3d1635cd056","inline_address":"4 Riverside Mead, Peterborough","public_address":"Riverside Mead, Peterborough, PE2","postcode":"PE2 8JN","bedrooms":4,"bathrooms":3,"receptions":2,"floor_area":null,"plot_area":null,"land_area":null,"property_type":"Detached House","property_age_bracket":null,"construction_year":null,"status":"Sold STC","sale_status":"Sold STC","lettings_status":null,"owner_label":"Vendor","tenure":null,"tenure_notes":null,"lease_expiry_year":null,"lease_expiry_date":null,"public_url":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/platform\/properties\/4fd57964-71ea-4a77-b773-b4079a0f95dc","created_at":"2022-06-17T16:39:19+01:00","updated_at":"2022-07-19T11:39:26+01:00","custom_meta_data":[],"property_urls":[],"viewing_booking_url":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/platform\/properties\/4fd57964-71ea-4a77-b773-b4079a0f95dc\/book-viewing"},"relationships":{"address":{"data":{"type":"address","id":"03d1a68a-6f4a-42ff-bf65-5b9768d6ce81"}},"details":{"data":{"type":"details","id":"f2b1a173-0611-4014-a980-894257b0bab0"}},"salesListing":{"data":{"type":"sales_listing","id":"be1cec3a-cf2f-40c4-a627-427cf3fbdfa7"}},"lettingsListing":{"data":null},"primaryImage":{"data":{"type":"media","id":"125542ce-27f1-4852-8fb6-b71daaaa70d1"}}}}],"included":[{"type":"address","id":"433518e4-d544-42ce-aba4-7d1137465af1","attributes":{"anon_address":"London Road, Peterborough, PE2","line_1":"101 London Road","line_2":"Peterborough","line_3":null,"town":"Peterborough","postcode":"PE2 9DD","inline":"101 London Road, Peterborough, PE2 9DD","longitude":-0.2465764,"latitude":52.560172}},{"type":"details","id":"1bf2b0fc-36c1-40f1-9e04-5b5cf72ffd0c","attributes":{"display_property_style":null,"work_required":null,"heating_system":null,"council_tax_band":null,"council_tax_cost":null,"local_authority":null,"service_charge":null,"service_charge_period":"month","service_charge_notes":null,"ground_rent":null,"ground_rent_period":"month","ground_rent_review_period_years":null,"ground_rent_uplift":null,"ground_rent_expiry":null,"full_description":"<p>Tortoise Property are pleased to offer this five bed detached house that is situated in the popular location of London Road, Fletton.<br><br>**Please call for either a viewing or virtual tour of this property.**<br><br>The property has a hallway, ground floor bathroom, bedroom, kitchen, dining room, lounge and converted garage on the ground floor. There are four bedrooms and the family bathroom on the first floor.<br><br>Outside the property has a front garden, a back garden and off-road parking for four cars.<br><\/p>","short_description":null,"location_summary":"London Road is a great location that is situated within walking distance of the city centre and local amenities. The Queensgate shopping centre is an 16 minute walk. The train station is a 21 minute walk or 5 minutes by car. The Kings secondary school is a 6 minute drive.\r\n\r\nPeterborough City Centre can be reached by car in 5 minutes and by bus in 10 minutes.\r\n\r\nThe A1 Junction can be reached by car in 11 minutes and the surrounding parkways give access to the A47 both east and west. \r\n\r\nWe love Fletton because of the lifestyle you can enjoy here. Great homes, close to nature and superb facilities make this one of our favourite places to live and work.","has_parking":null,"has_outdoor_space":null,"virtual_tour":null,"shared_ownership":false,"shared_ownership_notes":null,"shared_ownership_rent":null,"shared_ownership_rent_frequency":null,"shared_ownership_percentage_sold":null,"created_at":"2022-06-17T15:18:54+01:00","updated_at":"2022-06-17T15:28:08+01:00"}},{"type":"sales_listing","id":"992114a6-3fcf-48b1-af1d-f5f3976a23da","attributes":{"status":"For Sale","price":300000,"price_qualifier":"In Excess of","display_price":true,"archived":false,"is_low_profile":false,"occupancy_status":1,"new_home":false,"created_at":"2022-06-17T15:29:16+01:00","updated_at":"2022-06-17T15:29:57+01:00"}},{"type":"media","id":"9ed40865-0873-4159-808b-5941faa520c9","attributes":{"name":"136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000","order":0,"is_featured":true,"feature_index":1,"title":null,"is_image":true,"url":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg","urls":{"thumbnail":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_thumb","small":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_small_fill_crop","medium":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_medium_fill_crop","large":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_large_fill_crop","hero":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_hero","full":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844548\/136511_31517777_IMG_17_0000.jpeg"}}},{"type":"address","id":"03d1a68a-6f4a-42ff-bf65-5b9768d6ce81","attributes":{"anon_address":"Riverside Mead, Peterborough, PE2","line_1":"4 Riverside Mead","line_2":"Peterborough","line_3":null,"town":"Peterborough","postcode":"PE2 8JN","inline":"4 Riverside Mead, Peterborough, PE2 8JN","longitude":-0.2305068,"latitude":52.5631968}},{"type":"details","id":"f2b1a173-0611-4014-a980-894257b0bab0","attributes":{"display_property_style":null,"work_required":null,"heating_system":null,"council_tax_band":null,"council_tax_cost":null,"local_authority":null,"service_charge":null,"service_charge_period":"month","service_charge_notes":null,"ground_rent":null,"ground_rent_period":"month","ground_rent_review_period_years":null,"ground_rent_uplift":null,"ground_rent_expiry":null,"full_description":"<p>Here at Tortoise Property, we pride ourselves on doing things differently, by offering a complete partnership and consistent approach to construct a comprehensive marketing package tailored for the single purpose of selling your property as agreed at the initial valuation.<br><br>\"Tortoise provided me with a comprehensive property management service over a four year period, offering a friendly, transparent and consistent relationship.<br><br>When I decided to sell my property I immediately engaged with Tortoise to undertake the action. They actively advertised my property, were proactive with local sale opportunities and provided timely updates on progress. The sale on my property was agreed, exchanged and completed within five weeks. I would highly recommend Tortoise Property for their professional and friendly approach.\" - Tracey Matthews - Testimonial <br><br>Valuations<br><br>We concentrate on the maximum price your house is likely to sell for then agree a sensible timeframe for which the property should be sold whilst clearly explaining how the fee you are charged, is invested in enabling us to find your buyer from across the country.<br><br>\"I recently used Tortoise to sell my house, Chris came round and went through everything there price was better than all others I had received and they seemed a lot more genuine.\" - James Richards - Testimonial <br><br>Relationship management<br><br>Our relationship managers are here to personally look after you offering complete transparency and guidance throughout the sales process, following a 12-week programme that provides regular viewings with prompt feedback.<br><br>\"They say selling your home can be very stressful, not with this team, there was never a time you could not get in touch with these guys. You will be in safe hands all the way from start to finish.\" - Maxine Ambrose - Testimonial <br><br>Facebook<br><br>The growth of our sales portfolio into the wider Peterborough area we believe is the result of our unique strategy to capture maximum exposure. Facebook provides us with the opportunity to target our property marketing and expand our reach beyond the property portals.<br><br>Facebook live<br><br>The potential reach of a digital tour is limitless. Our live feed property tours on facebook are great for potential buyers to not only view the property but to ask relevant questions and get instant replies from wherever they are based.<br><br>Online and traditional auctions<br><br>Our property auction service gives you the ability to sell your property at auction either online or at a live auction. The buyer pays a commission so your house is sold at no cost to you. The buyer must complete within 28 or 56 days meaning your property is sold fast.<br><br>Performance-related fees<br><br>Here at Tortoise we do offer traditional fee structures based on a standard percentage of the purchase price or a fixed fee. However, we are so good at what we do that we are confident enough to offer you performance related fees we believe we should win together.<br><br>24\/7 services<br><br>Property sales can be daunting, especially if it is your first time. Here at Tortoise, we have real people available to talk to 24 hours a day 7 days a week as well as a live web chat so that you can chat to someone at your convenience.<br><br><br><br><br><br>Negotiator awards<br><br>In 2017 Tortoise Property was shortlisted for website of the year in the negotiator awards competing with large national estate agency chains illustrating the quality and presentation of our brand and level of service.<br><br>Our micro-site offers plenty of information so please choose from one of the tabs on the left that is applicable to your requirements and we look forward to seeing you in the near future or to find out more about us and our services visit www.tortoise property.co.uk<br><\/p>","short_description":null,"location_summary":null,"has_parking":null,"has_outdoor_space":null,"virtual_tour":null,"shared_ownership":false,"shared_ownership_notes":null,"shared_ownership_rent":null,"shared_ownership_rent_frequency":null,"shared_ownership_percentage_sold":null,"created_at":"2022-06-17T16:39:20+01:00","updated_at":"2022-06-17T16:45:16+01:00"}},{"type":"sales_listing","id":"be1cec3a-cf2f-40c4-a627-427cf3fbdfa7","attributes":{"status":"Sold STC","price":350000,"price_qualifier":"Fixed Price","display_price":true,"archived":false,"is_low_profile":false,"occupancy_status":1,"new_home":false,"created_at":"2022-07-19T11:38:08+01:00","updated_at":"2022-07-19T11:39:26+01:00"}},{"type":"media","id":"125542ce-27f1-4852-8fb6-b71daaaa70d1","attributes":{"name":"136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000","order":0,"is_featured":true,"feature_index":1,"title":null,"is_image":true,"url":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg","urls":{"thumbnail":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_thumb","small":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_small_fill_crop","medium":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_medium_fill_crop","large":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_large_fill_crop","hero":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg?tr=pr-true,n-property_hero","full":"https:\/\/ik.imagekit.io\/street\/street-mobile\/properties\/general\/844609\/136511_31519016_IMG_00_0000.jpeg"}}}],"meta":{"pagination":{"total":2,"count":2,"per_page":250,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1}},"links":{"self":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/api\/property-feed\/sales\/search?page%5Bnumber%5D=1","first":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/api\/property-feed\/sales\/search?page%5Bnumber%5D=1","last":"https:\/\/inventorymanchester.co.uk\/api\/property-feed\/sales\/search?page%5Bnumber%5D=1"}}
```

So the idea is we have "id" going into Pid, "inline_address" going into "inlineaddress" and so on. I don't need to store everything that's a part of the JSON string. Just parts that match the db columns if that makes sense.

Comment: You could use a TVP to pass it in bulk. Another possible option is passing the whole JSON string (without desrializing) and parsing it in SQL Server. Without seeing your attempt, or what exactly you are trying to achieve, we can't help. Please add also your SQL table definitions.

Comment: I'll add my SQL table in just a mo so you can see what I'm trying to parse it to.

I need to deserialize it as each value needs to be stored in its respective column. I.e. "inline_address needs to be stored in the column "inlineaddress" in the db and so on.

TVP after a quick google would be the method I'm probably looking at since I would like to store each value in a column within a table in my sql database.

Comment: @Charlieface I hope this is more like what you expected and will assist further. Apologies, alot of this is still very new to me and I'm trying my best to follow formats that make more sense. I appreciate all your support so far!

Comment: I strongly recommend you upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server

Comment: Upgrading my SQL Server version to 2016 in a bid to use this method you have outlined as the upgrade would be a worthwhile and means better support in the future too. 

I will let you know how I get on with the method you've provided once the upgrade has been completed.

Comment: If you're upgrading you might as well jump to 2019

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246784/discussion-between-donovan-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you ALREADY have a nice parsing system of the data setup, and you ALREADY have a nice class object that represents the json which is now a great easy to use class object?

Then all we need and are asking here?

How can I insert a row of data into a table?

The above is YOUR ONLY question here.

So your code (warning - air code follows), will be somewhat like this:

```
string strSQL
  = @"INSERT into [Tortoise_Street_Properties]
    (Pid, InLineAddress) VALUES(@Pid, @Address)";

 // replace TEST4 and properites with your conneciton string.
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
 {
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
    {
     cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.attributes.Pid;
     cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.attributes.InLineAddress;

     conn.Open();
     cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

So, you simple outline the columns, setup the values from the object, and then insert the values.

We really don't care if you have 3 vars A, B, C, are reading a text file, or you have that complex json object.

Your goal, your question, your quest?

How can I insert some data into a database. That is the skill set and goal of yours.

edit:
The only issue is that some of the data is "repeating", and thus above simple insert code shows the field mapping and a simple insert of data into a table? You might have a outer loop - a for each on the particular data array. But, remember, you have a class type EVEN  for those repeating data, and you want to use that class defined for the array.

You have STRONG typed data with that existing class, and you are now free to pull out data from the class with great ease. Simple find and get the data you want from that class, and use a simple SQL insert statement as per above.

Also, for creating say half a dozen little inserts? VERY little need to create a stored procedure for each routine - just code out the simple SQL and insert as per above. I would only write a gazillion little insert stored procedures if you need them in more then one place in your code. Writing a stored procedure for what amounts to a simple one line SQL insert is a formula for world poverties  - it just not required.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to bulk insert this might be to send the whole JSON string to SQL Server and parse it there using `OPENJSON`.

This is a somewhat complex JSON, as it has references in its properties to other properties.

Therefore it's probably best to first parse out the `included` array values into a table variable, then join it back to the main array.

- It's unclear where you get `virtualtour` from, so I've left it out.
- Note the data types, your current types leave what to be desired. `latitude` should not be an `int`, it should be a `decimal`, and `price` should not be `varchar`. The IDs appear to all be `uniqueidentifier`.
- You don't need to specify a path if the property name is an exact match.
- Nested arrays with more than one object must be parsed using a separate `OUTER APPLY OPENJSON`. In this instance you don't have any apart from `included` which we are parsing separately into a table variable.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.InsertJSON
  @json nvarchar(max)
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @included TABLE (id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, attributes nvarchar(max));

INSERT @included (id, attributes)
SELECT j.id, j.attributes
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.included')
  WITH (
    id uniqueidentifier,
    attributes nvarchar(max) AS JSON  -- for whole JSON object
  ) j;


INSERT dbo.Tortoise_Street_Properties
  (Pid, inlineaddress, postcode, description, bedrooms, price, salestatus, brochure, longitude, latitude)
SELECT
  main.PId,
  main.inline_address,
  main.postcode,
  details.full_description,
  main.bedrooms,
  listing.price,
  main.sale_status,
  media.url,
  addr.longitude,
  addr.latitude
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    Pid uniqueidentifier '$.id',
    inline_address varchar(255) '$.attributes.inline_address',
    postcode varchar(20) '$.attributes.postcode',
    bedrooms int '$.attributes.bedrooms',
    sale_status varchar(255) '$.attributes.sale_status',
    address uniqueidentifier '$.relationships.address.data.id',
    details uniqueidentifier '$.relationships.details.data.id',
    salesListing uniqueidentifier '$.relationships.salesListing.data.id',
    primaryImage uniqueidentifier '$.relationships.primaryImage.data.id'
  ) main

LEFT JOIN @included Iaddr ON Iaddr.id = main.address
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Iaddr.attributes)
  WITH (
    longitude decimal(9,6),
    latitude  decimal(9,6)
  ) addr

LEFT JOIN @included Idetails ON Idetails.id = main.details
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Idetails.attributes)
  WITH (
    full_description nvarchar(max)
  ) details

LEFT JOIN @included Ilisting ON Ilisting.id = main.salesListing
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Ilisting.attributes)
  WITH (
    price int
  ) listing

LEFT JOIN @included Imedia ON Imedia.id = main.primaryImage
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Imedia.attributes)
  WITH (
    url varchar(255)
  ) media
;
```

Your C# code should look like this

- Use `await` wherever possible.
- Pass parameters with the exact `SqlDbType` and precision/length.

```cs
...
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               var properties = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               await InsertJSON(properties);
           }
....
```

```cs
private static async Task InsertJSON(string json)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertJSON", conn))
    {
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@json", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = json;  // -1 means max
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        await comm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting several errors with what's been outlined above. The first being that InsertJSON requires an object reference. Which is a bit confusing when we've got the function.

Then I'm also getting syntax errors with the use of the word "with" in the sql. Any thoughts? many Thanks again!

Comment: Fixed typos, should work now. `InsertJSON` will need to be `static` if you are calling it from another `static` function

Comment: Ok so the 'InsertJSON' part no longer has errors, it's now the SQL to go through as it has an issue still with the syntax near the keyword 'with' apparently in all cases where with is used. The exact error reads: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertJSON, Line 32

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have `select @@version`? Because `OPENJSON` is only available from 2016 onwards

Comment: Ah, I'm running SQL Server 2014.. That would be why. I should have stated that in the question. I'll edit that now.

Comment: Hmmm you'll have to use a TVP. I'll leave you to work that out, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/71915357/14868997

Comment: Why even being to bother with a TVP and having sql server try to deal with json data when he ALREADY has a deifned class and newtonsofft breaking that json out to a super nice class that already parsed out the data? The user has a few values, wants to insert into the table - don't even need a store proc here at all. Busy day - maybe tonight I'll post a few lines of code of how to insert a row of data into a table, since that simple solution seems to have escaped the posters here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Because the JSON contains an array in `$.data`, which could be arbitrarily large. Inserting a large number of values in a loop could be slow.

Comment: Well, we not determined we have a huge amount of json. And if we only adding a few rows of data, then not a big deal. So, yes, if this is a big data migration, then sure. but in the VAST majority of cases, some values received from a web service is not going to be a large payload, and by the posters information, we ALREADY been told this is a web service call.   Been at this for a VERY long time, and some web api is not going to return a gazillion rows - so lets make reasonable assumptions here then right? That web api from what we can tell returns ONE property of information.

Comment: See my post below - the goal here is to insert a few rows of data into a database. Really not a complex goal, and since we have the json strong typed class, then a few simple inserts into the database is all that we require here.

Comment: Turns out this has become slightly more complicated. As there is a second JSON data string to deserialise and I need to then take data from the first, to apply it to the second in order to fetch the deeper level of information. Will keep you all posted on my progress if you wish.

Comment: This seems to suggest that based on the first json data, you now have to make another web service call, or are you saying that more data from the json has to go into other tables? (this is expected). And in my other post - I noted how you want to build a routine for taking that json data  as a "separate" function to add to each single table you have. So, not clear where the 2nd json string comes from, but the overall approach should be much the same as how the first example worked.